# MySql Returns error when using function WEEK() with modes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that I can't make function **WEEK(date, mode)** to work.

I have an SQL where I am grouping sums by year and then by week:

```
SELECT SUM(o.total) as total_org, SUM(o.total_eur) as total_eur, 
WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as period, YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as smallerperiod, `s`.`domain`
FROM `orders` `o`
JOIN `shops` `s` ON `o`.`domain_id` = `s`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`domain_id` = '5'
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)), WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR))
ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC
```

Which **works exactly how I want** except weeks starts from number 0. I found out that mode that would work the best for me is number 3, so I tried to change my SQL to:

```
SELECT SUM(o.total) as total_org, SUM(o.total_eur) as total_eur, 
WEEK('DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)', 3) as period, YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as smallerperiod, `s`.`domain`
FROM `orders` `o`
JOIN `shops` `s` ON `o`.`domain_id` = `s`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`domain_id` = '5'
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)), WEEK('DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)', 3))
ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC
```

However it just gave me the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC

EDIT:
I tried to make it work without single quotes too:

```
SELECT SUM(o.total) as total_org, SUM(o.total_eur) as total_eur, 
WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3) as period, YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as smallerperiod, `s`.`domain`
FROM `orders` `o`
JOIN `shops` `s` ON `o`.`domain_id` = `s`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`domain_id` = '5'
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)), WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3))
ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC
```

However, it returns me the same error

Comment: Remove the quotes here: `'DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)'`

Comment: Indeed, I have but it changes nothing, I get the same error with quotes or without.

Comment: And you have an extra bracket here: ` HOUR)', 3))`

Comment: Yes! Jens. Thank you. I am feeling so dumb now. Could you post it as the answer so I can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I have done it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the single quotes arround  `'DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)'` because you want to call a funtion and not use it as a string.

You get theeroor, becuase you have an extra bracket here: `HOUR)', 3))`

So the query must be:

```
SELECT SUM(o.total) as total_org, SUM(o.total_eur) as total_eur, 
WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3) as period, YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as smallerperiod, `s`.`domain`
FROM `orders` `o`
JOIN `shops` `s` ON `o`.`domain_id` = `s`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`domain_id` = '5'
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)), WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3)
ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove that last bracket after `WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3))` .Otherwise everthing is perfect i had tried same.
You can also tried below code.

```
  SELECT SUM(o.total) as total_org, SUM(o.total_eur) as total_eur, 
    WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3) as period, YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) as smallerperiod, `s`.`domain`
    FROM `orders` `o`
    JOIN `shops` `s` ON `o`.`domain_id` = `s`.`id`
    WHERE `o`.`domain_id` = '5'
    GROUP BY 
    YEAR(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR)),
    WEEK(DATE_ADD(o.date_created_utc, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), 3)
    ORDER BY `smallerperiod` ASC, `period` ASC
```